# should I update my Android System version 7.1.1 to 8.0 in a phone Z835?

Tags: updates, hardware, zte

Hello I am new here and I have phone android mark `ZTE` model `Z835` and I would  like update but I dont know if my phone support tha update.

**details about my phone:**

- **model: `Z835`**
- Android version: `7.1.1`

  if you need more information about my phone could you comment bellow and I give you more information.

Comment: If the update is offered for your phone, why shouldn't it be supported? If it's not offered *for your device* you cannot update anyway (there's no such thing as a "generic Android image/install", so it must always be specifically made for the device to be used on). That considered, what remains of your question then?

Comment: from this link it shows latest android as 7.1.1 by AT&T released in Jan 2018. I don't know more about this device and  other service providers. https://www.att.com/devicehowto/tutorial.html#!/stepbystep/id/stepbystep_KM1246107?make=ZTE&model=ZTEZ835